# Dynamically create necessary jQuery(document).on

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin that uses `jQuery(document).on()` to activate a modal.  I have a bunch of modals on the page.

If I manually create an `.on` for each modal *opening/closing* everything works as

```
jQuery(document).on('opened', '[data-remodal-id=modal-1]',
  function() {
    player1.api('play')
  });

jQuery(document).on('closed', '[data-remodal-id=modal-1]',
  function(e) {
    player1.api('unload')
  });

jQuery(document).on('opened', '[data-remodal-id=modal-2]',
  function() {
    player2.api('play');
  });

jQuery(document).on('closed', '[data-remodal-id=modal-2]',
  function(e) {
    player2.api('unload');
  });
```

However this is a managed page, that could need 2,3 or 10 modals with their own content. I'm trying to do what I did above, only dynamically.  Here's my attempt, and I can see why it doesn't work, but I have no idea how to approach this properly.

```
var countPlusOne;
for (i=0;i<players.length;i++){

    countPlusOne=i+1;
    var dataSelector = '[data-remodal-id=modal-'+countPlusOne+']';

    jQuery(document).on('opened', dataSelector, function () {
      players[i].api('play');
    });

    jQuery(document).on('closed', dataSelector, function (e) {
      players[i].api('unload');
    });
}
```

Hopefully it gives you some idea of what i'm trying to do? Is it even possible?

Comment: The issue is that the value of `i` inside the closure is not what is expected, so I agree with @Juhana about which other question to refer to

Comment: @Juhana Thank you, it was closures, I thought it was going to be more complicated than that, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If `playerX` are global vars, you could refactorize your code to this:

```
jQuery(document).on('opened closed', '[data-remodal-id]', function (e) {
  window["player" + $(this).data("remodalId").replace('modal-' ,'')].api(e.type === "opened" ? 'play' : 'unload');
});
```

But i guess you don't need all this different `playerX` variables anyway.
Ultimately, your `api()` should handle player id and it would be called like that e.g:

```
player.api(1, 'play');
```

**EDIT:** Ok i'm miss this part in OP

> I'm using a plugin

So you shouldn't override `api()` method.

**EDIT2:** to answer your question, using closure, you could use:

```
var countPlusOne;
for (i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    countPlusOne = i + 1;
    var dataSelector = '[data-remodal-id=modal-' + countPlusOne + ']';

    jQuery(document).on('opened', dataSelector, function() {
      players[i].api('play');
    });

    jQuery(document).on('closed', dataSelector, function(e) {
      players[i].api('unload');
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you have dynamic elements and have to bind events to them.

You can try something like this:

```js
var count = 1;
function addInput(){
 var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var input = "<input id='txt_"+count+"' class='input'>";
  count++;
  content.innerHTML+=input;
}

function registerEvents(){
 $(document).on("blur", ".input", function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
  })
}
registerEvents();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<button onclick="addInput()">Add input</button>
```